# Two columns layout in ViewPager

Tags: android

I would like to make 2 panel (2 columns) layout in ViewPager for tablet version when in horizontal configuration. Something similar to what TED application achieved. On the left a List and on the right Details depending on list choice.

What's the best approach to get it done ?

Comment: I am not sure what ViewPager has to do with the two-column layout

Comment: That you are swiping over many views which are designed to be 2 panel layout like that: http://developer.android.com/images/fundamentals/fragments.png

Comment: Ok, understand.  Then what's the problem with designing a layout containing the two fragments?